# Am I using Paired Statistical Test Correctly?

Tags: data-visualization, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, paired-comparisons, paired-data

I am comparing a feature between correct & incorrect trials. There are N=1194 paired samples $\{x_i,y_i| i=1,2,...N\}$, where x is for correct trials and y is incorrect trials.

I am using a nonparametric Mann-Whitney test to test the hypothesis $x>y$. (although I get similar results with a normal t-test)

My results show that x>y with P-value of P=2.3e-11 (very confident). Furthermore, by using a log-transform & getting the difference of the medians, I get that median(x) is 48% greater than median(y)

So far, these are great results. But then I plot my data, as shown below. Left figure is a boxplot with grey lines being individual samples. Middle plot are histograms of x,y (top) and their paired differences (bottom). Right plot is a scatterplot of the data {x,y}.

[image: data]

Although looking at the bottom histogram of paired differences, x is clearly greater than y, looking at the boxplot & scatterplot it seems like theres a huge amount of variability. Thus my P-value of P=2.3e-11 seems EXTREMELY confident, and the ratio of medians of 48% seems too high.

Am I doing this right?

Comment: Some reasons to explain this are:

1) MW whitney tests & t-tests only describe the difference of the mean; they say nothing about the variablity about the mean.

2) I have a huge amount of data (N=1194) to give me very high power)

3) My data is positive & negative, so the 'ratio' of medians is meaningless.

Comment: (2) and (3) are correct, but (1) definitely is not: *all* statistical tests--and these two are archetypical examples--specifically account for variability.  However, the variability they address is the *sampling variability* of the statistic, not the variability of the data themselves. See our threads about [sampling distributions](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22sampling+distribution%22).

Comment: @whuber do you think its reasonable to get such a low P value for a scatterplot/boxplot that visually looks so equal?

Comment: Yes: the histogram displays an SD of about 0.5, whence the standard error of the mean will be approximately $0.5/\sqrt{1100}\approx 0.015$. A mean difference of $0.077$ would therefore be about $5$ se's away from $0$, which is highly significant.

Comment: @whuber, so I follow your argument & agree that the confidence in the SEM seems reasonable. However, in this case the SEM doesnt seem to tell the whole story since the populations are so overlapping. Ie, from only looking at the SEM & % change (+40%), one might get an unrealistic view of how different the populations are. I guess my question is, what metric would you suggest to use that would describe the fact that eventhough the means are significantly different, the populations are still very similar?

Comment: [Effect size](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=effect+size).  For the M-W, this is best measured as an estimate of the chance that a random $X$ will exceed a random $Y$.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thnx!